# Epplus : how to display double quaotes in string concatenation formula

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I want to display something in col 1 as following:

```
  Unique Identifier       Display_Reg    Year   Month   Region  LO Count    
        2016_Apr_ENY    ENY     2016    Apr Albany     10   
        2016_Mar_ENY    ENY     2016    Mar Albany     11
```

I am getting values in Cells of col 1 as:

```
 worksheet_LO.Cells[Rowcount, 1].Formula = "=CONCATENATE(C" + Rowcount + "," +"D" + Rowcount + "," + "B" + Rowcount + ")";
 worksheet_LO.Cells[Rowcount, 1].Calculate();
```

Above gives me result as **2016AprEny**. 
How to Display Underscore among them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Goal is to end up with this formula in the cell:

```
=CONCATENATE(C1,"_",D1,"_",B1)
```

To achieve this you need to add the `,"_",` string into your concatenation where you had just the `,`. in order to do this we need to be careful to escape the `"` character by adding another in front.

This should do it:

```
worksheet_LO.Cells[Rowcount, 1].Formula = "=CONCATENATE(C" + Rowcount +@",""_"","+"D" + Rowcount + @",""_""," + "B" + Rowcount + ")";
worksheet_LO.Cells[Rowcount, 1].Calculate();
```

Comment: apologies - i initially forgot the @ sign before the string literals - corrected now